# How to add a new child node in Firebase Realtime Console Read-only and non-realtime mode activated in the data viewer to improve browser performance

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I have a question, which i have not been able to figure out.

My Firebase Realtime Database has the following message:

> Read-only and non-realtime mode activated in the data viewer to improve browser performance
> Select a key with fewer records to edit or view in realtime

So I understand if I want to view and add new children node under nodes already created, but how would I add a `brand new` child node under the main database?

It wont allow me to add cause of the `read-only` message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the path at the top and navigate to where you want to add the data. As the console has to render less data, it won't be in real only mode then.

[image]

You can also navigate by clicking on the relevant nodes if you don't want to edit the URL manually. The other option left would be to write a script that updates the data.